# if fg and f are differentiable at a, must g be differentiable at a? If not, what condition is needed to imply that g be differentiable at a?

Tags: derivatives

if $fg$ and $f$ are differentiable at $a$, must $g$ be differentiable at $a$? If not, what condition is needed to imply that $g$ be differentiable at $a$?

I realized that people asked similar question before, like
"If $f+g$ and $f$ are differentiable at $a$, must $g$ be differentiable at $a?$" It can be easily proved by using limits.

However, when it comes to multiply, I find it no longer eligible to use limits to finish the proof.

Comment: Using $f(x)  = 0$ could give $fg$ differentiable for all $g$.

Comment: But is it possible that even if $f(a)≠0$, g is still not differentiable? How do you know $f(a)≠0$ is the only condition needed to imply that $g$ is differentiable?

Comment: It is not possible, $fg$ and $f$ both differerntiable at $a$ and $f(a)\neq 0$ imply that $\frac{fg}{f}$ is also differentiable at $a$.

Answer (score 2):

The most commonly referenced non-differentiable function is $g(x)=|x|$. Let $f(x)=x$. Then $f$ is differentiable, as is $fg$.

Obviously, if $f$ and $fg$ are differentiable at $a$ and $f(a)\neq 0$ then $g=(fg)/f$ is differentiable at $a$ by the usual quotient rule.

Comment: But is it possible that even if $f(a)≠0$, g is still not differentiable? How do you know $f(a)≠0$ is the only condition needed to imply that $g$ is differentiable?

Comment: @XXWANGL Because if $f(a) \neq 0$, then $g(a) = \frac{(fg)(a)}{f(a)}$. The right side is differentiable because $f(a)$ and $fg(a)$ are both differentiable, so we can apply the quotient rule. This forces $g(a)$ to be differentiable, requiring only that $f(a) \neq 0 $

Answer (score 1):

f=x and g=$\sqrt x$ at 0 fg=x$\sqrt x$ g is not derivable at 0